# Trigger that doubles value on update

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi what I am trying to do is a trigger that will double the value of the quality on update.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_price
AFTER UPDATE ON "Producer"
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN (:new.Ranking>:old.Ranking)
BEGIN
      UPDATE "Elements"
      SET Quality = Quality * 2
END;
```

This is  what I tried to do but I get errors and don't really know how to fix it. I could not really find a case that had similar errors like I do. And whenever I try to fix the code I just get a different one.

Comment: can you post the error message?

Comment: You really really really need to post the error messages,